# Why does sort and reverse an array in Javascript give the desired output

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

```
var sortedSquares = function(nums) {
    const squaredArray = []
    for(let i=0; i<nums.length; i++){
      squaredArray.push(Math.pow(nums[i], 2))
    }
    let arrayWithoutZeros = squaredArray.filter(ele => ele!=0 && ele !=1)
    let arrayWithZeros = squaredArray.filter(ele => ele === 0 )
    let arrayWithOnes = squaredArray.filter(ele => ele === 1)
    let finalArray = arrayWithoutZeros.sort().reverse()
    finalArray.unshift(...arrayWithOnes)
    finalArray.unshift(...arrayWithZeros)
    return finalArray
};

const nums = [-4,1,0,3,10]
sortedSquares(nums)
```

Output: `[ 0, 1, 9, 16, 100 ]`

So when i call  the above function, I thought alright 0's and 1's end up in the end of array , well i wrote an array without it

But when writing this question i realized

```
var sortedSquares = function(nums) {
    const squaredArray = []
    for(let i=0; i<nums.length; i++){
      squaredArray.push(Math.pow(nums[i], 2))
    }
    let arrayWithoutZeros = squaredArray.filter(ele => ele!=0 && ele !=1)
    let arrayWithZeros = squaredArray.filter(ele => ele === 0 )
    let arrayWithOnes = squaredArray.filter(ele => ele === 1)
    let finalArray = arrayWithoutZeros.sort()
    finalArray.unshift(...arrayWithOnes)
    finalArray.unshift(...arrayWithZeros)
    return finalArray
};

const nums = [-4,1,0,3,10]
sortedSquares(nums)
```

Output : `[ 0, 1, 100, 16, 9 ]`

Even sort doesn't return the desired output

What is the reason behind this, Is this because arrays are Objects in Javascript

Comment: You should better read what [`unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) does. It adds *to the beginning* of the array.

Comment: Is there any reason why `sortedSquares()` does all the steps it does? Why do you extract the `0`s and `1`s _after_ squaring all the elements, then sort the _other_ elements, and then prepend the `0`s and `1`s again? Just square all elements and sort them o.O - `[-4,1,0,3,10].map(x => Math.pow(x, 2)).sort((a, b) => Math.sign(b - a))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is that numbers are getting sorted **as strings** and NOT according to the actual number value. Therefore `100` is placed before `16` in the sorted array. (The `0`s in `100` have have priority compared to the `6` in `16`)

> The sort() method sorts the elements of an array in place and returns the sorted array. The default sort order is ascending, built upon converting the elements into strings, then comparing their sequences of UTF-16 code units values.

[`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Simplified demonstration:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 9, 16, 100, ];

console.log(arr.sort()); //[1, 100, 16, 2, 3, 9]
```

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 9, 16, 100];

console.log(arr.sort());
```

This is how you could sort by number values:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 9, 16, 100, ];

console.log(arr.sort((a, b) => a -b)); //[1, 2, 3, 9, 16, 100]
```

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 9, 16, 100];

console.log(arr.sort((a, b) => a - b));
```